# How to define range of months for any year on Django model?

Tags: python, django, date, methods

I have a Django model called Event that has a date field for the date of the event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
```

I'd like to be able to set a method on the model to tell whether the event is a "spring semester" event or a "fall semester" event.

The spring semester would be defined as January to May. Fall is August to December.

My goal is to be able to filter by either semester in a generic list of events for a year.

How would I go about writing the method defining each semester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is:

```
class SpringSemesterEventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SpringSemesterEventManager, self).get_query_set() \
            .filter(is_spring_semester=True)

class FallSemesterEventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FallSemesterEventManager, self).get_query_set() \
            .filter(is_fall_semester=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def is_spring_semester(self):
        month = self.event_date.month
        return True if month >= 1 and month <= 5 else False

    @property
    def is_fall_semester(self):
        month = self.event_date.month
        return True if month >= 8 and month <= 12 else False

    objects = models.Manager()
    spring_semester = SpringSemesterEventManager()
    fall_semester = FallSemesterEventManager()
```

Then in a view you can do:

```
fall_events = Event.fall_semester.all()
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Wait, you are filtering (which uses a SQL `WHERE` clause) on properties of an instance? How this could work? Even if it does work, it would be extremely inefficient, since it implies iteration over all objects of the queryset.

Comment: The OP asked for a model method that could determine whether or not an Event instance was a "spring" or "fall" event. Whether you're retrieving one object or hundreds, determining if the month falls into a particular range is going to require iteration over each object. A better way to do this would be to set a separate value when the model is saved that examines the event_date and determines "spring/fall/whatever". That field could then be indexed for very fast searching. When I get some free time, I'll update the example.

Comment: I think there's no need for the separate value. Just update those methods on the manager, to return a QuerySet filtered like this: `return super(SpringSemesterEventManager, self).get_query_set().filter(event_date__month__gte=1, event_date__month__lte=5)`, and delete those properties/methods from the model.

Comment: Actually, it might be a good idea to leave the properties on the model so you can query an instance, but not query the properties in the manager.

Comment: @Mandx, the suffix `__month__lte` didn't work for me on Django 1.4 (I get an AttributeError). Maybe it's the old Django version, can someone confirm if this works?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at django's Models' methods? You can find them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()

    def get_season(self):
        import datetime
        """
        Returns the event's specific season
        """
        if 1 <= datetime.date.today().month < 4:
            return "Winter event"
```

Obviously the code above in incorrect, but you know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use filter on a date range, using __gt (greater than) and __lt (less than) operators:

```
Event.objects.filter(event_date__gt=datetime.date(2011, 1, 1), event_date__lt=(datetime.date(2011,6,1))
```

Or you can write the semester into the db, you can for instance override the default save() method so this is done automatically whenever you save a new or existing event. So the model would be:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # determine if the even is in the spring or fall
    if self.event_date.month in [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.semester = 'spring'
    elif self.event_date.month in [8,9,10,11,12]
        self.semester = 'fall'
    super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Then you can simple query Event.objects.filter(semester = 'spring')